# JSP: Changing an image based off java value

Tags: jsp

So I've made a for loop and as it iterates it will use ajax / jquery to update values, but my issue is in how it will update the code of the page itself

Say I have an image tag that loads a graph:

```
<img src="http://dev-server07:8080/graphs/ChartGen?PID=<% rs.getDouble(i) %>&minutes=720&height=30&width=1200"/></div>
```

Obviously doesn't work, but I'm not really too sure on what to do to fix it?  In my head that should load

```
<img src="http://dev-server07:8080/graphs/ChartGen?PID=962&minutes=720&height=30&width=1200"/></div> Or something like that. Is there some escaping I'm screwing up?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img):

> src = URL potentially surrounded by spaces Specifies a URL referencing
>   a non-interactive, optionally animated, image that is neither paged
>   nor scripted.

You can load images dynamically using the [JavaScript Image class](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/image.html), for example.

Cheers

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?  I'm assuming that I can't just do

myImage = new Image() 
myImage.src = "path/img.gif"

Comment: Why do you assume not? That's exactly what you do.